# bootstrap css file and jquery js file are not linked in thymeleaf header file

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I am a newbie of spring boot. The below image shows the folder location of my bootstrap css file and jquery js file on spring boot thymeleaf template.

[image]

And these are my home html scripts

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
    <div th:fragment="header-css">

        <title>Spring Boot Blog</title>

        <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />

    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="header">
   .....
```

But css and js scripts are not linked at all. 
Any idea, please!

**== UPDATED ==**

I am evaluating [the spring blog example](https://github.com/reljicd/spring-boot-blog). I think my problem is related to login controller. First this is the login controller codes.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Principal principal) {

        String username = (principal != null ? principal.getName() : "ANONYMOUS");

        if(principal != null) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }

        // ALWAYS PRINTING "ANONYMOUS is WRONG!!!!" 
        System.out.println(username + "  is WRONG!!!!"); 

        return "/login";
    }
}
```

And even more

```
return "/login"
```

line brings wrong files. In below login.html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <div th:replace="/fragments/header :: header-css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div th:replace="/fragments/header :: header"/>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <fieldset>
```

the controller call the following css file and display its contents.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
```

Comment: Well your code looks all right. Could you share your Thymeleaf configuration? Also, if you are using Spring Security there is a special configuration you must add to be able to link resources. So maybe also add your Spring Security configuration?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Please check the updated part.